# How to stream from Oracle Cloud Streaming to Elasticsearch Kafka Input Plugin?

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have set up Oracle Cloud Streaming all the way from pools to the stream itself configured as public, I am trying to use Logstash to pull the data and get it stored in Elasticsearch, and want to know how.

I am new to Oracle Cloud and Kafak but I tried setting up Kafka connections like mentioned in this link [(Collect logs from OCI Logging into Logstash using OCI Streaming as a Kafka server (oracle.com)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/oci-logs-streaming-kafka-logstash/#task-2-set-up-the-logstash-server) but I still get the following error:

```
Aug 21 12:46:34 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:34,922][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] Successfully logged in.
Aug 21 12:46:35 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:35,044][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] Kafka version: 3.3.1
Aug 21 12:46:35 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:35,044][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] Kafka commitId: e23c59d00e687ff5
Aug 21 12:46:35 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:35,044][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] Kafka startTimeMs: 1692621995041
Aug 21 12:46:35 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:35,047][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Subscribed to topic(s): ElasticTestStream
Aug 21 12:46:35 elastic-test-instance logstash[83786]: [2023-08-21T12:46:35,686][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector][main][77a8f87059d62472ce4dd50365d6a9cde1c012fd075cbce9573dee55541451fd] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Failed authentication with cell-1.streaming.me-jeddah-1.oci.oraclecloud.com/192.29.227.128 (channelId=-1) (Authentication failed)
```

Any suggestions to make this work ?

---

## Edit 1:

I figured out my user didn't have enough permissions, so I created a dedicated user for this task with enough permissions and tested it with Logstash it worked fine and I was able to get the data.

My `jaas.cong` looks like this:

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="{TENANT}/elastic-test-user/{OCID_STREAM_POOL}"
  password="{AUTH_TOKEN}";
};
```

and my `pipeline.conf` file looks like this (don't mind the output it's just for debugging that I am getting the data from stream)

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "cell-1.streaming.me-jeddah-1.oci.oraclecloud.com:9092"
    topics => ["oracle-logs"]
    security_protocol => "SASL_SSL"
    sasl_mechanism => "PLAIN"
    jaas_path => "/etc/logstash/jaas.conf"
    auto_offset_reset => "earliest"
    consumer_threads => 1
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  file {
    path => "/tmp/output.txt"
  }
}
```

with this everything checks out and data are coming through.

Now I want to use the Elastic Agent configured using Fleet instead of logstash, I have copy pasted the configurations for the Cuatom Kafka Logs Integration from `pipeline.conf` as follows and left the rest to the default:

```
Host => bootstrap_servers
Topics => topics
Group ID => "elastic-consumer"
Username => username
Password => password
```

but I ended up with this error in agent logs:

```
16:19:37.327 elastic_agent.filebeat [elastic_agent.filebeat][error] Error initializing kafka consumer group
```

Thats the farthest I could get

Comment: Please look over your jaas.conf file and make sure this is configured correctly. Can you connect using kcat or kafka-topics.sh --list ?

Comment: You should show your logstash config, in the post itself, please. Alternatively, you could try Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink rather than logstash

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I was able to connect through Logstash and updated the post of my attempt to connect through Elastic Agent.